# libevent... configure: error: not found, cannot proceed

Tags: compiling

I received the following error while trying to build `pgBouncer` from source.  This occurred during the configure phase (OS:Ubuntu12.04). Any solutions?

```
checking for library containing gethostbyname... none required
checking for library containing hstrerror... none required 
checking for crypt... yes checking for lstat... yes 
checking for libevent... configure: error: not found, cannot proceed
```

Comment: Just FYI `pgbouncer` (version 1.4.2) is available from the standard Ubuntu 12.04 repository.

Answer (score 2):

It needs the libevent to be installed in your OS.
Install libevents with apt-get or install it from source.

There are many link in the google on how to install libevents.

Comment: The required package is **libevent-dev** I think